# How To get a Navbar over grid structured background

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

I am trying to create a Responsive Website, and I am stuck at one point. I want to create a header with grid system.
for eg.,
I have created a Header divided into two parts;

1. col-md-4  : For Image
2. col-md-7  : for Some Text

Now I want my nav bar on this Header and It must be transparent. How to Do that ???
I have tried giving "position: absolute" but When I create a new section, that section is visible under the navbar, I don't want this.. Please help...

Desired Output :
[image: Click here to see the output that I want]

Comment: Please share the code. Please make sure it's a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your css and html files:

```
css:
.navbar{
 position: absolute;
 width: 100vw; 
 z-index: 1000; // to be on top
 margin-top: 10vh;
}

html:
<your-toolbar class="navbar"></your-toolbar>
```